# How To wipe the last canvas paint in qml

Tags: javascript, canvas, qml, qt5, qtquick2

```
Canvas {
    id: canvas
    onPaint: {
        if (personalInfo.count === 0) {
            return
        }
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        var points = []
        for (var i = 0; i < personalInfoModel.dataCount(); i++) {
            var temp = personalInfoModel.get(i)
            points.push({
                            date: temp.date,
                            heartRate: temp.heartRate,
                            temprature: temp.temprature,
                            pressure: temp.bloodPressure
                        }
                        )
        }
        drawAxis(ctx)
        drawGridLineAndUnitNum(ctx, chart.activeChart, points, "x", 15); 
    }
}
```

I have two button. If button `A` is clicked, then set `chart.activeChart` to `7` and call `cavas.requestPaint()` on `A::onClicked`,  on `cavas.drawGridLineAndUnitNum` draw seven vertical line. If button `B` is clicked besides set `chart.activeChart` to `30`, all same to `A::onClicked`. I hope that when `A` is clicked, canvas wipe the drawn line which product by `B` is clicked and vice versa. But in fact, it always reserve the line draw by last time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`Context2D`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html), associated to a specific `Canvas`, provides two useful functions:

- [`fillRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#fillRect-method)
- [`clearRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#clearRect-method)

In most cases, it could be possible to "clear" a `Canvas`simply by filling it with the background color, i.e. by using `fillRect`. That's the approach of the [StocQt example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-demos-stocqt-example.html), which has a `white` background.

However, if the background is `transparent`, filling it does *not* remove other strokes and thus does *not* make much sense. In this case, the only possible way to clear the `Canvas` is by removing all the strokes, i.e. by using `clearRect`.

I use a transparent background and thus `clearRect` is the way to go for me.

Comment: thanks you to edit and correct my answer.English is not my mother language.I can't clearly express my thought so as to only write a short snippet.I am moved by your serious.I will do hard to payback this community